# How can I put dynamic values in an HTML string that comes from a JSON file in React?

Tags: html, reactjs, string, dynamic, jsx

Edit:
Solved

---

I need to replace HTML chunks that comes from a string with Dynamic Values in React. The string comes from a JSON file, so I can't use backticks.

For example:
I want to replace the text `__Replace__` with a dynamic value.

```
//Simplified for easy reading.
const jsonData = {content: '<div>Result = __Replace__ <div>'}
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState('')

function App() {
  return (
    </div>

       <input onChange={ setInputValue }>
       
       <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: jsonData.content }}></div>  

    </div>
  );
}
```

```
//So this: <div>Result = __Replace__ <div>
//Will render like

//Input Value: 1
Result = 1

//Input Value: 2
Result = 2

//Input value: 3
Result = 3
```

I can use the JS **replace** method every time the input changes to re-render the whole text, but I think is the less efficient way to do it, is just as bad like this example I made.
[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/late-shadow-sbdkn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: [react-jsx-parser](https://github.com/TroyAlford/react-jsx-parser)

With react-jsx-parser, I can have JSX code in simple strings and being stored in JSON files, so I can edit my string with any WYSIWYG editor and still have **dynamic values**.

You can see my code and files here:
[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-fast-sfdrr?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

The text structure is in the JSON file.

I'm using components with Context API instead of props, because if I use props, the whole text re-renders.

[Gif Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aqbz.gif)

I hope someone find this useful. <3

Answer (score 0):

I don't clearly understand your question but if I'm right, try this:

```
function App() {

//A state that's going to be changed by the user with an input
const [name, setName] = useState('Jenell') //This replace the <b>Name</b> with a new Value
const [price, setPrice] = useState(100) //This replace the <b>Price</b> with a new Value

return (
    <div className="App">
        {/*Inputs for the users that change the states NAME and PRICE*/}
        <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)} />
        <input type="text" value={price} onChange={(event) => setPrice(event.target.value)} />


        <h3>Hello {name} , the price is {price} .</h3>
        {/* 
  First rendered result should be:
  Hello Jenell, the price is 100*
  /}

  {/* If the user change the input, the text should change inmediately:
  Hello NewName, the price is NewPrice*/}

    </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry for the nonsense text I put before, I already edited my question to be more concise. I want to load the HTML data from a JSON file, so sadly, I can´t use JSX expressions like <div>{ value }</div>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `backticks` like this:

```
const replace = 5;
`<div>Result: ${replace}</div>`
```